# É normal não aparecer nada indicando se implementei anúncios corretamente no meu aplicativo?

Tags: android, android-activity

Obviamente que não espero que apareça nenhum anúncio verdadeiro, mas algum indicativo de que fiz o procedimento corretamente para saber assim se está tudo certo.

1ª imagem (Preview Android Studio)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2ª imagem (Aplicativo na máquina virtual)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostrado nada aparece, então não tenho ideia.

**XML da activity**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit"/>
```

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso você testou os ads de teste oferecidos pela própria adMob (precisa setar os id's conforme o tutorial do AdMob e usar um device Id de emulador, também tem no tutorial). Esses sempre aparecem. Normalmente os banners reais não aparecem quando os id's ou o json é inválido, mas os de teste sempre aparecem.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=pt-br

Comment: Se você criou uma conta recentemente como um publicado, os anúncios irão demorar alguns instantes para aparecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionando as seguintes linhas, consegui resolver a minha questão:

**MainActivity**

```js
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class

private AdView adView01;
private AdRequest adRequest01;

onCreate

adView01=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView01);
adRequest01=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView01.loadAd(adRequest01);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]